# Как спарсить строку из XML и записать в базу?

Tags: php, xml, mysqli

Нужно получить все строки из XML заключенные в теги `<name>Значение</name>`, и записать все в MYSQLi. Пробовал разные варианты, но что-то не получается( Еще проблема в том что сам XML размером 800 Mb... Подскажите как это правильнее сделать? Если можно пример кода (PHP)

Comment: *Пробовал разные варианты, но что-то не получается* - что имеено вы пробовали, и что не получается?

Comment: это больше похоже на текст для проекта [fl.ru](http://fl.ru), где я вам и советую заказать написание данного скрипта

Comment: Пробовал XML Reader, запускал циклом, но не получалось получить строку, по этому и спрашиваю, возможно кто наглядней покажет как сделать... Скрипт сам по себе не сложный пара строк... Возможно не получается из-за размера файла. Его возможно потоково спарсить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ обновил, костыли убрал.

### Правильное решение конечно через [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php)

Статьи по теме

- http://instanceof.org/xmlreader-php-example/
- http://instanceof.org/xmlreader-simplexml-example/

Например если xml вида

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <name>
        Title1
    </name>
    <name>
        Title2
    </name>
</root>
```

то php код будет

```
// создаем объект читающий xml
$reader = new XMLReader();
$filePath = "/path/to/file.xml";

if (!$reader->open($filePath)) {
    die("Failed to open $filePath");
}

// смещаем курсор по всем элементам, включая дочерние
// если дочерние элементы не нужно проверять, то лучше использовать $reader->next()
while($reader->read()) {
  // проверка на элемент и название элемента
  if ($reader->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name === 'name') {
     // получаем текст внутри элемента
     $title = $reader->readString();
     // обрабатываем и пишем в БД
  }
}

$reader->close();
```

Comment: Спасибо 'korytoff', выручили)))

Comment: @korytoff  правильнее было бы, мне кажется, показать , как работать с xmlreader, чем такие заглушки делать - http://php.net/manual/ru/book.xmlreader.php

Comment: @splash58 как работать с XMLReader можно и в документации посмотреть, а здесь я предложил вариант как читать файл построчно и не забывать оперативку целым файлом. Конечно еще надо бы добавить блокировку на файл

Comment: @korytoff xmlreader не читает весь файл в память. впрочем, неважно

Comment: @splash58 да, тут я скорее всего был не прав, использование XMLReader действительно предпочтительнее

Comment: @korytoff Если вы считаете, что можно улучшить ваш ответ, пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь правкой (ссылка «править» под ответом).